# Script for getting CPU utilization of particular cores

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, cpu

I am looking for a script for checking CPU utilization of particular CPU Cores. We have 80 cores, We need get CPU utilization percentage for particular 4 cores.

Comment: Why doesn't your OS use all the cores equitably? Since you seem to imply that somehow the OS favors or disfavors some cores, or somehow associates processes or threads with specific cores, I think that you should explain the setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **dstat**:

If your machine has 4 cores. You can do following

`dstat -C 0,1,2,3,total`

If you only want to see stats for cores 2 and 3 you can do following:

`dstat -C 2,3`

I'm guessing that with 80 cores you know the ID of the cores you want monitored. Use those values instead.

Or you can use **top** to dynamically see your core utilization. Run `top` from term and then press `1`

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html
https://linux.die.net/man/1/dstat